# How can I make the fancyhdr footer to be longer than \textwidth?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

I'm using XeLaTeX with `fancyhdr`. I need to have the footer wider than `\textwidth`. This is an intentional effect. The problem is that the footer is several lines long, so I want them to appear as a single paragraph, wider than `\textwidth`. I'm not sure how best to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\cfoot{\hspace*{-.1\textwidth}\parbox{1.2\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
```

It doesn't look great, and you'll probably have to increase how much space the footer is allowed to take up, but you get the picture...

Comment: (Replace `\lipsum[1]` with the relevant text...)

Comment: `fancyhdr` had an offset option for this!