# How to get page number to the right of \textwidth

Tags: formatting, header-footer, numbering, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I would like to set my page numbers to the bottom right to the right of \textwidth. I have a couple figures that have long footnotes and the page numbers are currently on top of this. While not ideal, I would just like to move the page numbers more to the right to not overlap with the text.

Based on [How to set page number at right footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153167/how-to-set-page-number-at-right-footer) and [How can I make the fancyhdr footer to be longer than \textwidth?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25954/how-can-i-make-the-fancyhdr-footer-to-be-longer-than-textwidth), I have tried this:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}
\cfoot{\hspace*{-.1\textwidth}\parbox{1.4\textwidth}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
```

However it doesn't seem to work. How can I change it to get what I want?

Comment: Which document class you use? How you set your page layout? Using `geometry` package? Page number and footnote are not in the same space for typing. They won't overlap each other unless you have negative `footskip` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to the solutions you posted would be something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\hspace*{-.1\textwidth}\parbox{1.2\textwidth}{\hfill\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-14] % dummy text

\end{document}
```

[image: page number in margin]

Though I think you're supposed to do it using `\fancyfootoffset`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset[R]{2.5em}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-14] 


\end{document}
```

Either way you'll probably have to fiddle with the lengths to get what you want.

Comment: Yes, `\fancyfootoffset` is the proper way.